# How to reset a jmeter user defined variable (counter) to an initial user defined value

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter I have nested loops: an outer ForEach loop, with an inner LoopController.  Inside the inner LoopController, I have a user defined variable being incremented with each inner loop. To increment that variable, I am using the config element "Counter".
Once the inner LoopController completes because it has hit its max loop count, it of course exits to the outer ForEach loop.  In that outer ForEach loop, I want to re-initialize that user defined variable (int) to an initial (non-zero) value before entering the inner LoopController again. Pretty basic stuff.

I'm using user defined variables. As an example:

```
initialValue=3
currentValue=${initialValue}  - initialize both variables to be the same
```

In essence, the logic is:

```
ForEach loop
currentValue=${initialValue}
  LoopController loop
     Increment currentValue using jmeter's Counter
Done
```

The problem is the currentValue variable keeps incrementing and is not being re-initialized back in the ForEach loop.

I've tried a number of different methods.  Currently, to re-initialize the currentValue variable within the ForEach loop, I'm using a Beanshell PreProcessor as follows (from an example I found in stackoverflow):

```
String x = vars.get("initialValue");
    int y = Integer.parseInt(x);
    String z = y;
    vars.put("currentValue", z);
```

I've also tried using the User Defined Variable config element inside the ForEach loop to set the currentValue to initialValue with each loop:

```
currentValue=${initialValue}
```

...but that doesn't work either.

I must be overlooking and/or over-complicating this, but jmeter seems to be treating the user defined variables in a not-so-obvious manner.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very possible to reset the counter value using JMeter Variables because the value it's being [managed by the Counter internally](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/modifiers/CounterConfig.java#L60) so if you really need to reset the counter value you will have to use [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) for accessing and setting the value of the given property.

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as a child of the ForEach Controller
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   def engine = engine = ctx.getEngine()
   def testPlan = engine.test

   def counterSearch = new org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass<>(org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.CounterConfig.class)
   testPlan.traverse(counterSearch)
   counter = counterSearch.getSearchResults().first()
   counter.globalCounter = vars.get('initialValue') as long
   ```

   [image]
3. Now your counter value should be reset on each ForEach Controller's iteration

   [image]

Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter.

---

Just remember if you bypass a JMeter limitation using reflection somewhere somehow a kitten dies so most probably there is a better way of implementing your use case, by the way are you aware of [intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum)?

Comment: Thank you Dimitr!  I will give this a try.  So you're using that code to set the internal value of the variable in Counter.  Seems very surgical.  I tried using a beanshell script to increment currentValue inside the Loop controller, instead of using Counter because I suspected something weird like that was going on.  However, I couldn't get that to work either, where inside the ForEach I would use another beanshell to set currentValue=${initialValue}. Not sure what the functional difference is between a beanshell sampler/preprocessor/postprocessor.